# Model not showing when creating a controller class

Tags: c#, asp.net

For some reason the add controller class dialog isn't picking up on the Movies, and MovieDBContext classing. I'm new to ASP.NET and Visual Studio 2010, is there something which I should do for the classes to show here?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you compile the project before you click on Add controller dialog?

Comment: have you compiled the project after you added the Movie class? otherwise the wizard won't show it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try building your project first and then add your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, have you got the latest [ASP.NET MVC Tools Update](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1491)

Answer (score 0):

Are domain and you web in the same project ? If no, Did you try to add the domain reference to you web app ?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 reasons for this:

- You haven't added the model to your DbContext
- You haven't compiled the project, before adding the controller